# Restarting spawn processes in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I have the below function, `setInterval`, which runs on a loop every second. I have a spawn process in the `startScript` function which kicks off an external python script. The loop runs perfectly the first time; however, when it loops through a second time, the `startScript` function is not kicked off. Why is this? Is there anyway to "re-spawn" the process?

Please note that after the script successfully runs once, it simply logs "closed", indicating the script is closed.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
var path = require('path');
var split = require('split');
var pythonData = [];

function startScript(){
  var pyScript = spawn('python', [ path.join(__dirname, 'script.py') ]);
  pyScript.stdout.pipe(split()).on('data', function(lineChunk){
    if (pythonData.length >=25){
      return pyScript.kill();
    }
    pythonData.push(lineChunk.toString());
  });

  pyScript.on('close', function(code){
    console.log("closed");
  });
}

setInterval( function(){
  if(some criteria){
    startScript();  
  }
  else if (other criteria){
    startScript();
  }
},1000);
```

Comment: what if neither `if` conditions are met?